# Flickr as image repository for php web application

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, flickr

I have a web application which allows their profile pic. since I had very small storage in my cloud I decided to use `flickr` as my image repository. I found that as a simple use case.
But when I am trying to implement the same I felt disappointed with `flickr` authentication process. I tried with `PHPflickr` and it gives `"Invalid Signature"` always, then I am tried with my own lib with oauth but their also I can't produce any improvement. their the problem was with permission.
Now I am totally confused *how can I do it, and Is it a good idea?*
Please give any clue *how can I do the authentication with php?*

Thank you

Comment: Despite your problem, using flickr as a image storage services violates their TOS.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I never found nothing about violation in their TOS document.

Comment: Look at "Use Flickr as a generic image hosting service for banner advertisements, graphics, etc." in https://www.flickr.com/services/api/tos/

Comment: Actually these are not adv or graphics just real image, I just using flickr as image repository, we are already using google+ as backup service, It is just like that, I am not able to find any violation till now, and if It is my misunderstanding sorry in advance..